# Dependency syntax of Gradle build script in Groovy

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, closures

For example the Groovy code like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'
}
```

I know `classpath` is a function and you invoke it by passing a string
But my questions are:

1. Is `dependencies` is a method of object `project`?
2. Is `classpath` a method of `project` or `dependencies`?
3. What does it mean when you pass a closure to a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the API docs, or navigating through the source. It helps to get your head around it. That said, there are all sorts of other things going on with delegates/owners and such, so it's not always clear on inspection where things are being called if you're not used to this aspect of Groovy. The descriptions and examples in the docs are likely going to be more useful for general usage.

`dependencies` is a method on Project, and is of type DependencyHandler. (Many if not most things you use frequently will live on Project)
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#dependencies-groovy.lang.Closure-
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html

In the dependencies block the `add` method of DependencyHandler gets called, with a 'configuration' and the dependency string. classpath here is a configuration used for the [buildscript itself](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies)

> What does it mean when you pass a closure to a function?

It means just that. Closure is a class in Groovy, and when you write this in Gradle you are creating a new closure and passing it as a parameter to a function (see the docs above, they reference `Closure` as a param in many methods). The [Groovy docs](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) can explain how they work better than I can. You can sort of think of it as a lambda, but it's not the same. It can execute code on its owner (usually the enclosing block/closure it's defined in) and can sometimes execute against its assigned delegate. If you're trying to work out how the Gradle configs work internally, *usually* you can find most of what you need on the class as above (e.g. mostly we're calling methods on DependencyHandler in this case). However the written documentation covers most common use cases.

Comment: Thank you danwalkerdev, I have been viewing the DSL ref and the delegation strategy of Groovy, now I know the `DependencyHandler` is passed to the closure as the closure's delegate so that the closure could invoke `add()` method of the `DependencyHandler`, but I still don't know where does the `classpath` come from, what do you mean "classpath here is a configuration"? Which object it belongs to? Thanks again, I'm new to Gradle.

Comment: Gradle has a thing called [configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) which represents a group of artifacts and dependencies. You can add your own, or a plugin might (android, java plugin for example), I think classpath is a built-in one for the buildscript. In the source code there is reference to a configurationContainer, so you can fetch them by name or by reference to the actual `Configuration` instance if you have it. `configurations` is available on Project (as I said, a lot of stuff lives there :) )